# Como omitir o espaço para inserir somente números em diferentes listas

Tags: c, arquivo, lista-encadeada

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct NBIG{
    int numero;
    struct NBIG *nseg;
    struct NBIG *nant;
}Nbig;    
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *nf,ch;
    Nbig *vem=NULL,*resmulti=NULL,*dasoma=NULL;
    Nbig *lista=NULL;
    Nbig *lista2=NULL;
    int cont,x,y;
    FILE *arq;

    if (argc>3) {
        // ficheiro
        for(cont=3; cont < argc; cont++){

            nf=strcat(argv[cont], ".txt");
            printf("%s",nf);
            arq = fopen(nf, "r");
            if(arq == NULL)
                printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
            else{
                fseek(arq, -1, SEEK_END);
                long posicao = ftell(arq);
                while(posicao >= 0){
                fseek(arq, posicao, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, arq);
                if (ch == ' ') {
                    dasoma=soma(dasoma, lista);
                    lista=apaga(lista);
                    vem=apaga(vem);
                    posicao=posicao-1;
                }
                else{
                    vem=makenode();
                    vem->numero= atoi(&ch);
                    lista=insertfirst(lista,vem);
                    posicao--;
                }

            }
            printf("\n");
            mostra(dasoma);
            printf("\n");
            fclose(arq);

                }
            }

            //printf("%d Parametro: %s\n", cont,argv[cont]);
        }
    }
    else{
    ...
    }
```

No ficheiro :
123 321

Nao percebo porque o código não funciona. recebe como 3º argumento um nome de um ficheiro e devolve isto.

> agrv(14077,0x7fff8f271380) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x7fd9f14026c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

A unica funcao que usa o malloc e esta

```
Nbig *makenode(){
    Nbig *R = (Nbig*)malloc(sizeof(Nbig));
    R->numero=0;
    R->nant=NULL;
    R->nseg=NULL;
    return(R);
}

Nbig *apaga(Nbig *L){
while (L!=NULL) {
    L=L->nseg;
    free(L);
}
return L;
}

Nbig *insertfirst(Nbig *A,Nbig *nv){
if(A==NULL){
    nv->nseg=NULL;
    nv->nant=NULL;
    return nv;
}
nv->nseg=A;
A->nant=nv;
return nv;
}
```

Comment: O erro aponta para um **free** sendo chamado para um objeto que não foi instanciado com **malloc** mas no seu código em nenhum lugar mostra um **free**

Comment: so se for quando chamou a função "apagar" lista

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na tua função `apaga`.

Nela tu apagas sempre o próximo do elemento não nulo (que pode ser nulo). Tenta mudar o teste para algo semelhante a isso:

```
Nbig *apaga(Nbig *L) {
  if (L == NULL)
      return NULL;
  while (L->nseg!=NULL) {
    L=L->nseg;
    free(L);
  }
  free(L);
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: persiste o mesmo erro

Comment: Debugando, onde ocorre o erro? Continua no mesmo lugar? Não tenho todo o código para investigar por ti...

Comment: é um if e um else  no else nunca entra pk passo 3 argumentos output:               1

21

321
agrv(28381,0x7fff8f271380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f814bc026c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: adicionei mais a função insertfirst

Comment: Amigo, não sei qual é o ambiente de programação que estás usando, mas todos possuem debugadores. Usa um debugador para executar linha a linha o teu código, então vê em qual linha está ocorrendo o problema. Observa também o valor das variáveis antes de cada instrução - assim tu poderás ver quando valores inesperados ocorrem (possíveis causas de erro). Após isso, diz onde está ocorrendo o erro - aí poderei te ajudar com maior precisão.

Comment: ele le o ficheiro começa a escrever para a lista e quando encontra o espaço no ficheiro nao executa mais devolve aquele problema deve estar no espaço, nao sei se e da função "atoi" que converte o caracter para inteiro

Comment: Se usares um debugador, poderás ter certeza se é da função `atoi` ou não. Todavia, já adianto que se o erro vier dessa função, ocorre um `undefined behavior` (comportamento aleatório por valor inválido) e não o erro relatado no enunciado da questão.

Comment: como faço debug via terminar

Comment: ja percebi onde ta o erro. A lista "vem" nao precisa ser apagada e quando  a posição chegar a -1 tenho de somar para devolver o resultado correcto.Portanto e so retirar a linha que apaga a lista vem